# php call variable from json array

Tags: php, json

from the below code, how can I call the value of `poet` from the array and set it in a php variable to use it for another query

What shall I write instead of `???` below

```
$ip = 1 ;
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM poems WHERE ip = '$ip' ");
$json1 = array();
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
array_push($json1, array('title' => $data['poem_title'],
        'body' => $data['poem_body'],
         'poet' => $data['poet'],
            ));
$poet = ???;
```

Comment: Why not just `$poet = $data['poet'];`???

Comment: not working, to be clear I want to get the variable out of the while loop

Comment: Well if it looped 10 times then you have 10 sub arrays each with a `poet`.  Which one do you want?

Comment: Looks like OP knows `poet` is the same value in every row for the query. I guess. If so, then `$poet = $json1[0]['poet'];` should work.

Comment: it works, thank you very much @GetSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to assign the value to a new variable, inside your loop. Your variable `$poet` will be available after the loop.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM poems WHERE ip = '$ip'");
$json1 = array();

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    array_push($json1, array(
        'title' => $data['poem_title'],
        'body' => $data['poem_body'],
        'poet' => $data['poet']
    ));
    $poet = $data['poet'];
}

// Your new variable is available
echo $poet
```

But what you're doing here doesn't really make sense because if you're looping through multiple rows of data, `$poet` will only ever equal the last row's value at the end of the loop. It will get overwritten on every iteration of the loop.

If, in your database, `ip` is a primary or unique key which you can guarantee to only retrieve one row, then you don't want to use a loop at all. You can just simplify it to:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM poems WHERE ip = '$ip'");
$json1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$poet = $json1['poet'];
```

Comment: yes, `ip` is primary and only one row is retrieved, actually your code solved many problems for me.. thanks a lot